# Implementing break-point function for ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, breakpoints, callstack

I'm implementing a break-point function for debugging my code in ruby.

my break-point function is like `breakpoint` in the code below.

```
 def breakpoint s
    color_s = "\033[1m\033[33m"
    color_f = "\033[0m\033[22m"
    line= (caller.first.split ":")[1]
    puts  "#{color_s}#{Time.new.strftime("%H:%M:%S")} line:#{line} -- #{s.to_s}#{color_f}"
    gets
 end

 a = 3
 puts "Hello World"
 breakpoint "test"
```

it will produce output like

```
 Hello World
 19:21:33 line:11 -- test
```

attention: `line:11` is the line number of where the function is called.

My question is How i can get variable names and values from program stack. for example in the code above: `a = 3`

Comment: is your "breakpoint function" a fancy `puts`, or should it actually break execution? Why don't you use `pry` or `debugger` instead?

Comment: a `gets` added for break execution.

Comment: What variable names and values?

Comment: question edited. i want function `breakpoint` prints the name and value of all variables in the caller context, here `a = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `binding` object of the current environment to do print local variables.

```
def breakpoint s, b
  b.instance_eval{local_variables.each{|sym| puts "#{sym} = #{eval(sym.to_s)}"}}
  ...
end

a = 3
breakpoint "test", binding
```

Comment: Error: `eval': can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)`

Comment: `b.instance_eval{local_variables.each{|sym| puts "#{sym}"}}` prints the names of variables in function `breakpoint`

Answer (score 0):

I modified sawa's answer:

```
 def breakpoint s,a
    color_s = "\033[1m\033[33m"
    color_f = "\033[0m\033[22m"
    line= (caller.first.split ":")[1]
    vars = eval('local_variables',a).map{|v| "#{v.to_s}= #{eval(v.to_s,a)}"}.join ";"
    puts  "#{color_s}#{Time.new.strftime("%H:%M:%S")} line:#{line} -- #{s.to_s} -- #{vars}#{color_f}"
    gets
 end

 a = 3
 g = 5
 puts "Hello World"
 breakpoint "test",binding
 f = 54
```

the output:

```
Hello World
22:58:40 line:13 -- test -- a= 3;g= 5;f=
```